# How to send email with images (embedded) in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, images, embed

There's no image insert button to use when composing an email. I want to insert image inside email content like the way we do with Outlook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update things for the new (as of April 2013) Gmail interface:

You have a few options:

- Drag the image from Finder/Explorer and drop it directly into your message.
- Mouse over the `+` sign at the bottom of the message, which brings up an "Insert" menu with a few options for photo sources. Select the camera icon, then browse to find the file on your computer.
- Use yifei's suggestion of switching back to the old compose method (This is likely just a transitional option, so it could be removed at any time.)

Comment: Yeah the new Gmail web now support insert images

Comment: Excellent, thank you, this is much easier :)

Answer (score 13):

You can enable this in labs:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/new-in-labs-inserting-images.html

> Turn on "Inserting images" from the [Labs tab](http://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&fs=1&view=pu&st=labs) under Settings

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

There are several procedure to insert images in GMail Message Body. Some of these I listed below:

1. You can use the "Inserting images" Lab feature to add images in your message body (mentioned by [Whitingx](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7635/how-to-send-email-with-images-embedded-in-gmail/7640#7640))
2. Read this useful post by [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/): [How to insert images and other HTML into Gmail](http://lifehacker.com/software/gmail/how-to-insert-images-and-other-html-into-gmail-197663.php)

   > For those of you who have tried inserting an image or table in Gmail, you've probably noticed that Gmail won't really allow embedded HTML (at least not in a traditional sense). In order to embed HTML, you actually need to copy the rendered HTML from either an existing web page or WYSIWYG HTML editor and then paste it into Gmail. Doing so allows you to insert your own tables, divs, images, etc. into Gmail pretty easily.
3. Just copy the picture from anywhere and paste it to the GMail's Message Editor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new Gmail compose interface, there is an arrow button at the right bottom corner. Click it to select to switch to the old fashion.

1. Edit your HTML in a text editor and preview it by any browser like Chrome/Firefox.
2. In browser, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then switch to your Gmail. Paste it to your email body.
3. The images should be shown as some placeholders in your email now. Click the image placeholder to select it, then click the "Insert image" button in the tool bar, upload image from your disk as an inline image in email.
4. Do this for all the images.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your Gmail page
2. In the top right side of the Gmail page, click on "Settings"
3. In the Settings box that opens, click on “Labs.”
4. Scroll down the list of options until you come to “Inserting images.” (It was a long way down on my system.)
5. Click “Enable.”
6. At the bottom of the page, click the button “Save changes.”

Now you are set up to insert images into an email message.

1. Open Gmail to compose a message.
2. The blank message will now have an icon added to the standard row of editing icons. If you look hard, it looks like some hills. Or place your mouse pointer over the new icon and a little message box will read “Insert image.”
3. Click on this icon and you will get a box that gives you the option to either browse on your computer to get an image file to upload or to enter the URL of an image file located on the Internet.
4. Once the image file is found, click "Add Image."

Good luck